# Лист переменных из массива

Tags: lua

Можно ли на lua создать лист переменных из массива?

```
R, G, B = getColors()
```

```
function getColors()
    return {255, 128, 0}
end
```

Comment: `R, G, B = getColors()[1], getColors()[2], getColors()[3]` Так работет, но я надеюсь на что-нибудь покороче

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте функцию `table.unpack`:

```
R, G, B = table.unpack(getColors())
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Просто надо было возвращать переменные не массивом, а через запятую

```
R, G, B = getColors()
```

```
function getColors()
    return 255, 128, 0
end
```